# how to make a TextView Scroll inside a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, textview

I have a two `TextView`s and `ImageView`s forming a cell in the `GridView`. The text in the `TextView` sometimes gets longer and covers the photo

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:lines="2"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

and this in the AdapterClass

```
productDescription.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

But when it's in the `GridView` it doesn't scroll and I tried to make it scroll horizontal but still hard to scroll.

Is there a certain UI advice how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after spending time for finding a way to work for my case i finally found a way to make it work smoothly through **HorizontalScrollView** and no need to add any java lines

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            ...
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```